# How to draw a custom shape in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I just want to draw a spin wheel. How to draw a circle like this?
[image]

Comment: see `CustomPaint`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution is to implement a custom painter ([CustomPainter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html)) then use the [arcTo](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Path/arcTo.html) method to draw each part of the wheel.

You can then set the color using `canvas.drawPath`.

Finally use it wherever you want using a [CustomPaint](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget :

**Full working example** :

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class WheelPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Path getWheelPath(double wheelSize, double fromRadius, double toRadius) {
    return new Path()
      ..moveTo(wheelSize, wheelSize)
      ..arcTo(Rect.fromCircle(radius: wheelSize, center: Offset(wheelSize, wheelSize)), fromRadius, toRadius, false)
      ..close();
  }

  Paint getColoredPaint(Color color) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = color;
    return paint;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double wheelSize = 100;
    double nbElem = 6;
    double radius = (2 * pi) / nbElem;

    canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, 0, radius), getColoredPaint(Colors.red));
    canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius, radius), getColoredPaint(Colors.purple));
    canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 2, radius), getColoredPaint(Colors.blue));
    canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 3, radius), getColoredPaint(Colors.green));
    canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 4, radius), getColoredPaint(Colors.yellow));
    canvas.drawPath(getWheelPath(wheelSize, radius * 5, radius), getColoredPaint(Colors.orange));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Wheel test'),
        leading: new Icon(Icons.insert_emoticon),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: CustomPaint(
        child: Container(
          height: 300.0,
        ),
        painter: WheelPainter(),
      ),
    );
    //]));
  }
}
```

Result :

[image: Colored wheel screenshot]

If you attemp to draw pie charts you better go with a Charting library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is it possible to add a widget like Text or Image in center of Arc?

Comment: I guess you can just stack text over it but you will have to do the math to place them correctly

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution with `CustomPainter` using `drawArc` method to draw each part of the wheel. Here you could also receive the colors and the number of divisions you want to have.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  void _drawSpeenWheel(Canvas canvas, Paint paint,
  {Offset center,
  double radius,
  List<double> sources,
  List<Color> colors,
  double startRadian}) {
  var total = 0.0;
  for (var d in sources) {
    total += d;
  }
  List<double> radians = [];
  for (var data in sources) {
    radians.add(data * 2 * pi / total);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < radians.length; i++) {
    paint.color = colors[i % colors.length];
    canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius),
      startRadian, radians[i], true, paint);
    startRadian += radians[i];
  }
}

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
 Paint paint = Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
 Offset center = new Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
 double radius = min(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

 _drawSpeenWheel(
   canvas,
   paint,
   sources: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   colors: [
     Colors.red,
     Colors.purple,
     Colors.blue,
     Colors.green,
     Colors.yellow,
     Colors.orange
   ],
   center: center,
   radius: radius,
   startRadian: 0.1,
  );
 }

 @override
 bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
   return oldDelegate != this;
 }
}
```

And then use it where you need it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speen_wheel/speen_wheel.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
   home: MyHomePage(title: 'SpeenWheel'),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
   ),
   body: SpeenWheel(),
  );
 }
}
```

**Working example**

[image]

Comment: This way you can add a widget on top of the `CustomPaint`. `CustomPaint(painter: new MyPainter(), child: Center(child: Text("Custom Text", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24.0),)))`

Comment: I need to add text in center of each arc. any ideas?

Comment: @ChyperX Use the Paragraph class or the TextPainter